# Eclipse: How to disable welcome screen?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-oxygen

I get an annoying welcome screen whenever I start eclipse.  How can I get it to skip the welcome and go straight to the workbench when I start it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Open Eclipse
2. Uncheck the box in the bottom right hand corner (Show every time)
3. Close the welcome screen

Comment: This was the right solution for me in Eclipse Neon. Small remark: In addition to unchecking the check box, you also should close the welcome screen tab once.

Answer (score 5):

The welcome screen is displayed whenever you first open eclipse with a new workspace.
Once you close the welcome screen, this is noted in the workspace, and on a restart of eclipse with the same workspace, you will not see it again until you either use the menu `Help/Welcome` or switch to a new workspace.

Note that you may have to really close the Welcome screen via the 'x' in its title tab; not just hide or minimize it.

Comment: This is not an answer on how to skip the welcome screen at startup

Comment: You're right. If you want to remove the welcome screen from a product, you would have to create the product yourself and NOT include any implementation of the `org.eclipse.ui.intro` extension point. With a given Eclipse IDE, you could try to just delete any `org.eclipse.ui.intro*` files from the `plugins` subdirectory of the product.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. There is a checkbox that needs to be unchecked.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the following steps for Eclipse Neon:

1. Go to Eclipse_Home\plugins
2. Take backup of the below jars and remove them from the above path

   1. org.eclipse.ui.intro.quicklinks_.jar
   2. org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_.jar
   3. org.eclipse.ui.intro_.jar
3. Step 3: Restart Eclipse

Comment: This worked for me on Eclipse 2019-06, which for some reason on Linux doesn't show the disabling checkbox on the welcome screen. I just did `mkdir plugins-hidden` followed by `mv plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro* plugins-hidden`, and the welcome screen is gone.

Answer (score 4):

STEP 1: Go to the eclipse home folder -> Go to plugins folder.

STEP 2: Search for org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal and remove it from the folder.

STEP 3: Now try to startup your eclipse with the new workspace and you can see that the welcome screen will not show up anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create file in your workspace:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.intro\introstate
```

and insert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<state reopen="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but it only unchecked the box "Show at startup" so that it will still show the first time

Comment: As of Eclipse 2019-12, this is the ONLY option to disable the welcome screen, as Eclipse removed the checkbox to disable that screen. (They did however leave the text next to the checkbox, though. Don't ask... It's Eclipse.)

Answer (score 4):

1 ) Go to **Help** Menu  
2 ) Click on **"Welcome"** 
3 ) Uncheck the **"Always show Welcome at start up"** in **"Welcome Page"** Right bottom Corner 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Eclipse Neon as an Administrator.
2. When Eclipse starts up with the welcome screen, uncheck the bottom right hand corner box.
3. Close the welcome screen from upper part with the 'x'.
4. Close Eclipse Neon
5. Reopen Eclipse. You will not see the welcome screen anymore. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

By creating the following file in your empty workspace:

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs
```

and fill it in with:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
showIntro=false
```