# Eclipse Photon, Skip Welcome, CheckBox missing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-photon

In the Eclipse Photon (1) release C/C++ [image: Eclipse Photon (1) Welcome Screen] the CheckBox to skip the Welcome Screen in future sessions is missing. Is there any other way to disable it in the settings?

Edit: I do not see checkboxes (but plusses?) in Help->Content->Scope->new [image]

Comment: I guess the root cause is missing checkboxes and radio buttons in the browser widget on Linux. Do you see checkboxes in: _Help > Content: Scope: New..._? Do you use [KDE with the Orion theme](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480243)?

Comment: I don't see checkboxes (but plusses?) otherwise (see edited screen shot). I use debian 9 with mate.

Comment: There should be checkboxes between each tree item handle (`[+]`) and the title. Are checkboxes shown in Firefox? E. g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: What O/S are you using? If Linux, see [**Welcome page not displayed properly Linux/Unix**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.8.php#mozTocId828477) in the Release Notes for Photon: _The default Welcome implementation is HTML-based and requires a supported browser in order to work. If no supported browser can be found, Welcome falls back to its Forms-based implementation, which has a different (simpler) appearance. Consult the SWT FAQ for supported browsers and setting up your browser to work with eclipse._

Comment: @howgler: yes, in Firefox (the test link) the checkboxes are visible.

Comment: @skomisa: I have Firefox and Chromium installed, that should work. And even if the Forms-based implementation is used it should be possible to have a Checkbox (?)

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy to disable the Welcome Screen by any other means (I am not too keen on clicking anyway :-).

Comment: OK - an alternative approach to getting rid of the Welcome screen is given in this SO answer: [Eclipse: How to disable welcome screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019185/2985643). It's for Neon, but I expect it is still valid for Photon. Note that this approach will also prevent the screen being shown when you open a new workspace, but it sounds like that would be OK with you anyway.

Comment: thanks to the tip I think I found a way. It is the file $WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro and therein is the tag "state" with "reopen" set to "true"; guessing a "false" worked after the third attempt (why on earth three times i don't know).

Comment: @pba It's good that you found a workaround for the missing checkbox, but could you post your solution as an answer? I think you found a new solution for this issue, and having it presented as an answer is more helpful to the community than having it buried in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a hint in the comments I found a solution. In the file

```
$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro/introstate
```

is a tag `state` with attribute `reopen` set to `"true"`. Changing that to  `"false"` worked. The complete modified file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<state reopen="false"/>
```